# Botframework No Interruptions from other Intent Dialogs until done with current Intent Dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I've intent A and B using LUIS.ai. In intent A I'm using `builder.Prompts.text` to ask user couple questions. However, sometimes depending on the answer it would switched to intent B. I'm guessing it happens to match with my intent B even though I think it shouldn't. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? If I'm going through intent A's dialogs, I don't want any interruptions from other intents until I'm done. Here is an example of my code.

```
bot.dialog('A', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        ...
    }, 
    function (session, args, next) {
        ...
    },
    function (session, args) {
        ...
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'A'
});


bot.dialog('B', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        ...
    }, 
    function (session, args, next) {
        ...
    },
    function (session, args) {
        ...
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'B'
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what `triggerAction`s do to you. They can be very handy to keep your dialogs open (http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-2-open-dialogs) but in your case they get in the way.

You can keep your dialogs *immune* to the global routing system, if you place them under the `IntentDialog`. If all you do is `A` and `B`, then this would be an un-interruptible equivalent of your code:

```
const intents = new builder.IntentDialog({
    recognizers: [
        new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_ENDPOINT)
    ]
});

intents.matches('A', 'A');
intents.matches('B', 'B');

bot.dialog('/', intents);
bot.dialog('A', []);
bot.dialog('B', []);
```

Comment: Reason I switched to `triggerAction` from `IntentDialog` is to use `cancelAction` to be able to cancel the dialogs when user types "cancel/stop". Is there a way to do that if I place my intents under the `IntentDialog`?

Comment: You sure can, with Intent.Dialog's [cancelAction](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentdialog.html#cancelaction). But in Pavel's code here he passes in a dialogId for his second parameter in `intents.matches`. This dialogId is in reference to the same dialogs you originally had sans `triggerAction`. So while the IntentDialog handles the intents, it redirects back to what you've been using so far (`UniversalBot.dialog`), allowing you to continue using `cancelAction`.

Comment: Not sure if I'm using it incorrectly but when I do `intent.matches('A', [...]).cancelAction(...);` anytime it matches my keyword `cancel` it goes to intent A's `cancelAction` instead of the intent I'm in (i.e. intent B). How would I make it not global? I basically have what Pavel has but I just want to add `cancelAction` to it and make it not global. Thanks

Comment: the `cancelAction` should attach to the *inner* dialog. You have attached it to the *outer* `IntentDialog` that is bound to `/`. You need something like `intent.matches('A', 'A')` and then `bot.dialog('A', [ ]).cancelAction()`. This would attach the cancellation action to the dialog `A` and not the `/`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is this:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(url) 
    .onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
        // LUIS is only ON when there are no tasks pending(e.g. Prompt text) 
        var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0; 
        callback(null, enabled); 
    });
```