# How can I properly prompt a user without having LUIS attempt to recognize the response?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a bot configured with a LUIS intent recognizer and although the initial root dialog starts as expected when LUIS recognizes the intent, if I prompt a user from within that dialog, the response the user sends back does not resume the suspended dialog but instead is sent back through the LUIS recognizer and begins a new dialog entirely.

This is my bot setup:

```
const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: config.get('bot.id'),
  appPassword: config.get('bot.secret')
})

super(connector, (session) => this.help(session))

this.set('storage', new BotStorage())

this.use(builder.Middleware.sendTyping(), new MessageSanitizer())

this.on('conversationUpdate', (message: any) => {
  console.log(message)
})

const recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(config.get('bot.model'))
this.recognizer(recognizer)
```

My dialog setup:

```
    this.dialog('/send', [(session, context, next) => {
  const amount = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(context.intent.entities, 'builtin.currency')
  const recipient = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(context.intent.entities, 'recipient')
  const product = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(context.intent.entities, 'product')

  session.send('Sure, I can do that.')
  session.beginDialog('/send/product', product ? product.entity : null)
}]).triggerAction({
  matches: 'send'
})

this.dialog('/send/product', [(session, query, next) => {
  if (query) {
    session.dialogData.productQuery = query
    next()
  } else {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What type of product did you want to send?')
  }
}, (session, results) => {
  if (results && results.response) {
    session.dialogData.productQuery = results.response
  }

  session.sendTyping()
  ProductService.search(session.dialogData.productQuery).then(products => {
    if (!products.length) {
      session.send('Sorry, I couldn\'t find any products by that name.')
      session.replaceDialog('/send/product')
    }

    const attachments = products.map(product => {
      const image = builder.CardImage.create(session, product.configuration.image)
      const valueLine = `$${product.value.min} - $${product.value.max}`

      const card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
        .title(product.name)
        .images([image])
        .text(product.description)
        .subtitle(valueLine)
        .tap(builder.CardAction.postBack(session, product.id))

      return card
    })

    const message = new builder.Message(session)
      .text('Okay, I found the following products. Please select the one you\'d like to send.')
      .attachments(attachments)
      .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)

    builder.Prompts.text(session, message)
  }).catch((err: Error) => {
    session.error(err)
  })
}, (session, response, next) => {
  console.log(response)
}])
```

At the suggestion of a reply below, I also tried to set up the recognizer as part of an `IntentDialog` rather than on the bot itself and then map the subsequent dialogs to that root dialog like so:

```
const recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(config.get('bot.model'))
this.intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })

this.intents.matches('send', '/send')

this.dialog('/', this.intents)
this.dialog('/send', [(session, context, next) => {
  const amount = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(context.entities, 'builtin.currency')
  const recipient = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(context.entities, 'recipient')
  const product = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(context.entities, 'product')

  session.send('Sure, I can do that.')
  session.beginDialog('/send/product', product ? product.entity : null)
}, (session) => {
  console.log('hello')
}])
```

However, this did not help, I am still getting the following error:

> / - WARN: IntentDialog - no intent handler found for None

Indicating that the response is attempting to match a new intent rather than resume the suspended dialog.

An example interaction with the bot that illustrates this issue:
[image: Image of the problem]

The 'typing' indicator will just continue indefinitely because its trying to match the 'None' intent but none exists.

Answer (score 1):

A match in the `triggerAction` will take precedence as every message received by the bot is sent through the routing system. You can customize it, but you can also try using the `IntentDialog` to isolate some of your flows from it.

More: [Botframework No Interruptions from other Intent Dialogs until done with current Intent Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351517/botframework-no-interruptions-from-other-intent-dialogs-until-done-with-current/43351847#43351847)

Comment: Hey, modified the original post to include my findings from your suggestion. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @DavidK, can you please share the sequence of user's utterances and bot responses?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest SDKs, you can achieve this without using `IntentDialog`. All you have to do is use `.onEnabled` on the `LuisRecognizer` without modifying any of your existing dialogs:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(url) 
    .onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
        // LUIS is only ON when there are no tasks pending(e.g. Prompt text) 
        var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0; 
        callback(null, enabled); 
    });
```