# How to use Prompts.text without triggering new intent in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have multiple dialogs that are triggered with `triggerAction`. I use LUIS to trigger/match utterances to specific dialogs.

Each dialog has two steps (functions):

1. if entities are valid query DB and end dialog, else prompt user for one of the missing entities with `Prompts.text()` and continue to next step
2. set dialog state and repeat dialog from step 1 with `next()` *

My problem is that for some prompted inputs (i.e. entity values) LUIS will trigger new unrelated dialogs. In these cases the dialog stack is lost (since I use `triggerAction`) and the conversation flow is broken.

How can I ensure that the prompt for missing entities will not trigger a new dialog? Is my conversation flow flawed?

I already have many trained utterances for each intent. I'm guessing my LUIS model is "loose" enough to match multiple word entities (entered after the prompt) to (short) intent utterances.

* From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-overview): *When a bot reaches the end of the waterfall without ending the dialog, the next message from the user will restart that dialog at step one of the waterfall.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LuisRecognizer.onEnabled()` to disable your LUIS calls while you're in the middle of a dialogStack, or even in the middle of a dialog. This will solve the issue of intents being recognized while you're in the middle of a Prompt.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/feature-onEnabled/app.js) I wrote on implementing the method when using a `RegExpRecognizer` (`.onEnabled()` is inherited from `IntentRecognizer`).

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765960/prompt-for-text-without-routing/45766525#45766525) to a Stack Overflow question that I wrote.

Comment: Steven, the link to the sample is missing

Comment: Yikes, thank you for pointing that out! Added link to the answer

Comment: Thanks for your response, in the end I opted for this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/43351847/6696049

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you found something that works for you. :)