# I want to use LUIS only in a specific module of the project

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am working on azure bot and using LUIS. I want to use LUIS only in a specific module rather than entire project.Is it possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What's your use case, what are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am making a chat bot for courses. There are multiple modules like user info, registration,course info and many others. I want to use Luis in only courses module and not for entire project for the reason of costing.

Comment: You can design in such a way like microservices. To say clearly you can implement the course info as a separate `function bot+Luis`. Refer my example [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Simple-Shopping-Assistant-188ec869?redir=0) and this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51490.microsoft-bot-framework-building-intelligent-chat-bot-using-azure-functions-and-luis.aspx)

Comment: I am using web app bot nodejs sdk v 3.0. Can same thing be applied to it? @Jayendran Can you share more details?

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434170/how-to-use-prompts-text-without-triggering-new-intent-in-microsoft-bot-framework/46434426#46434426) hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using LUIS in specific module you can use `LuisRecognizer.onEnabled()`
I hope it helps. For more details you can follow a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434170/how-to-use-prompts-text-without-triggering-new-intent-in-microsoft-bot-framework/46434426#46434426)